# cucumber custom made plugins

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

How to do i specify a custom made cucumber plugin in the test runner ?

Am getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The plugin specification 'UD.Plugin' has a problem:

Could not load plugin class 'UD.Plugin'.

Plugin specifications should have the format of PLUGIN[:[PATH|[URI [OPTIONS]]]
```

What is the expected format,

if my plugin is at Src/main/UD and the runner is at Src/Test/TestRunner

Note: i m using cucumber 4

Answer (score 0):

no custom plugin specification supported by cucumber

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mention

```
cucumber.plugin = com.test.support.ReportPlugin
```

in `junit-platform.properties`

My plugin file is in `src/test/java/com.test.support` and properties file is in
`src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties`

my relevant pom config is

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.9.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

plugin file looks like this

```
package com.test.support;


import io.cucumber.plugin.EventListener;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.*;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.UUID;

public class    ReportPlugin implements EventListener {

....
....
```